# Generator Matrix G

Tags: coding-theory

The question is:
Suppose C is a linear $[3,2]$-code over $\Bbb{F}_q$ with generator matrix $G$. Show that using
elementary operations, we can transform $G$ into one of the matrices:
$$
M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
$$
M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
$$
M_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

What matrix should I let $G$ be to begin the question?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Let $G$ be $\begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_2 & q_3\\ q_4 & q_5 & q_6 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @GitGud Hi, I'm still having a little trouble transforming G, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like (code) equivalence operations are also allowed. So you can also permute columns and multiply a column by a non-zero scalar. That is my somewhat educated guess, because otherwise the claim is obviously false.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes you are correct, Can you give me a hint on which operations I should use to start off with because I have failed up to now